# Is there a way to search for language data by context?

Tags: corpora

For example, if I wanted to see real-life transcriptions of dialogue in situations like a date, a business meeting, two friends walking in a park, etc, just to be able to generate lists of particular phrases, words or idioms people tend to use in such situations. I can search for words in a corpus, but not contexts. Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

When you are lucky, the corpus metadata have some information about the context. You can search corpus metadata on the [CLARIN Virtual Language Observatory](https://vlo.clarin.eu). Good luck!